# Windows Service not showing up when installed with Setup project

Tags: windows, vb.net, web-services, service

I have a simple windows Service developed in VS.net 2008 and VB.net. When I install the service using Installutil.exe from the command prompt it is working like a charm.

When I try to add a setup project and set the output and build and install it though it says successfully installed, it is not showing up in the services.

The event log shows that it is successfully installed. I just did check the registry, it did place the assemblies in HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\installer\assemblies.

But I don't understand why it is not showing up in the services listing. I refreshed and restarted.

Any thoughts??

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of ideas:

Are you installing under the same Windows account that you are attempting to run it under?  Do you have the Setup Project's "InstallAllUsers" property set to True?

Are you sure that you have the ProductName and Title properties in the Setup Project set correctly?  Maybe the service is showing up in the list under a different name, i.e., "SetupProject1" or something.

Similarily, in your service's ProjectInstaller class, in design view, look at the properties of the ServiceInstaller and make sure the ServiceName and DisplayName properties are set to what you want.

Comment: Thanks. I did check the InstallAllUsers to true and productname and title are correct. Even in the serviceinstaller it is correct. I even rebooted my machine. Eventlog shows service installed successfully.

Comment: This step didnt really help me solve the issue, the solution posted by rowmark below was the missing step in my case

Answer (score 12):

Found solution
You have to add a custom action in your MSI project.
So in custom actions, add the output of your service to the Install section. This will then run the required installation code for your service. i.e. the same as what the installutil.exe does

Thanks for all the help

Comment: Don't forget to do the same thing on the "uninstall" section, otherwise uninstalling the software will let a "ghost" service there.

Comment: I've done this, too. Software gets copied to the right places, but the service doesn't show in the list.

Comment: I skipped the step where you create an installer for the service inside the service project itself. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a(v=VS.100).aspx

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem and didn't pay attention to the portion BEFORE creating the Setup project.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a(v=VS.100).aspx

To create the installers for your service

In Solution Explorer, right-click Service1.vb or Service1.cs and select View Designer.

Click the background of the designer to select the service itself, instead of any of its contents.

With the designer in focus, right-click, and then click Add Installer.

By default, a component class that contains two installers is added to your project. The component is named ProjectInstaller, and the installers it contains are the installer for your service and the installer for the service's associated process.

In Design view for ProjectInstaller, click ServiceInstaller1 or serviceInstaller1.

In the Properties window, make sure the ServiceName property is set to MyNewService.

Set the StartType property to Automatic.

In the designer, click ServiceProcessInstaller1 (for a Visual Basic project), or serviceProcessInstaller1 (for a Visual C# project). Set the Account property to LocalSystem. This will cause the service to be installed and to run on a local service account.

Comment: This finally solved it for me (to get the correct service name) but also had to add the custom action as described by rowmark, otherwise no service was appearing at all

Comment: Great answer.  Solved it for me too

Comment: This is MAD. I know ProjectInstaller.vb is there somewhere, I know I have to include it, I've done that couple of times, but it gets me EVERY TIME! :-D